# ¿ Como crear enlaces a secciones de la misma pagina en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, enlaces-ancla

Quiero crear una pagina para añadir preguntas frecuentes que hacen los usuarios y evitarlos llamar por teléfono, enviar un correo o perder el tiempo de algún modo con las dudas que tengan.

Me gustaría crear un indice con la lista de títulos en la parte izquierda de la pagina, a modo de widgets de WooCommerce cuando muestran las categorías en el lateral del página de productos o en un Blog, que se muestran el resto de artículos del sitio web.
Y cuando pinche en cada titulo me dirija a una sección de la página en la que creare un sistema de acordeón para poner varias preguntas y sus respuestas.
Utilizo Quiero crear una pagina para añadir preguntas frecuentes que hecen los usuarios y evitarlos llamar por teléfono, enviar un correo o perder el tiempo de algún modo con las dudas que tengan.
Utilizo UX Builder, por lo que Para el diseño, podre hacerlo metiendo todo en un Row, y separando los títulos y los acordeones de preguntas, en dos Columnas diferentes

Muestro una captura y [un ejemplo](https://impossiblebakers.com/pages/faqs) de lo que quiero crear

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema de acordeón ya se como crearlo, pero tengo dudas sobre como debo crear los títulos de las secciones en la parte izquierda de la pagina.

No se como conseguir hacer esto
¿ Como puedo crear una pagina de esta forma sin utilizar Plugin?

¿ Como se consigue añadir enlaces a textos de la misma pagina ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al título en sección de preguntas debes de ponerle un `id` al bloque y en la parte de título de secciones con un `<a>` en el atributo `href` diriges a ese `id` ejemplo: `<a href="#pedidos" />`

Comment: Gracias @TrinidadMiranda. Eso ya tenía una idea de hacerlo, tengo más dudas a la hora de crear el Widgets, no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Usas algún plugin para el diseño como elementor, o lo estas haciendo con el editor de wordpress?

Comment: El tema que uso utiliza UX Builder, y no encuentro la forma de  crear un Widgets como el ejemplo. Quiza deba crear el Row, con dos columnas y utilizar css para conseguir ese diseño, ¿ Que opinas ?

Comment: El inconveniente que veo en esto, es que cuando pulso en el titulo de la izquierda, si que me dirige al enlace creado `#idElegido`, pero lo hace muy justo, y el titulo de la sección de la zona derecha, queda oculto en la parte superior. Lo ideal seria que cuando nos dirige a la sección elegida, quedara un poco de margen en la parte superior para poder ver perfectamente el titulo de la sección